# Azure IoT hub connection string not working anymore - Does azure update the connection string?

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string, azure-iot-hub

For some reason today after 2 months my IoT hub connection string did not work anymore which gave me a :

> Exception when sending message:{"Message":"ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized","ExceptionMessage":""}

I later found out that my connectionString changed in the IoT for which I use a free license. Even though I updated my connectionString to the new one I still get the same error which makes me wonder:

- Does Azure IoT hub require you to change your connectionString every now and then? If yes does anyone know a best practice to do this automatically?
- Does IoT Hub require you to have the most recent SDK's from Microsoft.azure.devices. and Microsoft.Azure.devices.client ?

As far as I know it just randomly stopped working over the weekend without any explanation and I have no clue why because there where 0 changes in the code or in Azure from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Hub relies on keys for access. Is there is a chance someone regenerated the key from the Shared Access Policy or via PowerShell?

You also mentioned you are using a free account - if you are sure you have the correct key, is there a chance your free trial has expired or exceeded the quota of 8,000 messages per day - [see the pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/iot-hub/).

As far as you questions are concerned:

1. Key cycling is not enforced by default.
2. I do not believe that the latest SDK must always be used.

Note that Event Hub is still in preview, so breaking changes are possible. I see you did mention IOT Hub, which works the same way for access control, but is a production service. It should be solid.

[image: Regen Keys in Azure Portal]

Comment: Hmm if MS does not do this for security reasons then this must have happend somewhere. Nobody changed it i am on the project but for now i will take this as a mistake i did somewhere.

even though i still cannot connect. I even updated all the SDK"S and I have zero idea why 0-o

Also as far as i know there isn't a limit to the free version.

Comment: The free tier gives you 8,000 messages per day. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/iot-hub/

Comment: Yea and i have 0 messages today. I like manually enable the project it's not constantly running. i use it for testing purposes.

Comment: This is also what makes it extra strange because i used it like the entire day 2 days ago and changed nothing. Now it's unauthorized.

Comment: Is there something in your environment that has changed? A firewall, a proxy? something else getting in the way?

Comment: Just checked. No even used my phone with 4g to verify and it has the same issues...

Comment: But this means that Microsoft does not require you to have the latest SDK or to update the connectionString once in a while. This means it's something else. Might just reinstall the RB-PI to check it out that way.

Comment: With 0 changes in the code, have you double checked you have not hit the message limit? Maybe some condition in your code did an unexpected loop? Look at "Total number of messages used" in the metrics.

Comment: checked the message limit and its standing at 0. even took a previouse branch which has the same problem. Will start reinstalling the pi now.

Comment: Ok I fixed it but because of this fix I will also close the question.
I disabled the pi again and moved the wi-fi dongle to another USB slot and then rebooted. Magically it worked out of nowhere.... So this question is related to something else and it doesn't answer anything so I will remove it later. 

Thank you for the help Murray nevertheless.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted. You can leave the question in place since I am sure someone may hit that key regen issues somewhere down the road.